# Laptop not detecting extra RAM

Tags: 20.04, ram, bios

I have an ASUS VivoBook S400CA with 4GB of built in RAM and an extra slot for additional memory. I have another stick installed but the BIOS and OS are still saying I have 4GB of RAM.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64 bit

The built in RAM is DDR3 1600MHz and the extra is a Crucial DDR3 1600MHz.

Some things I've tried

- I flashed the latest version of BIOS
- I ran memtest86 with no issues
- I have seated and reseated the memory

I would just like to know if there's anything else I can try to get it to detect my extra memory.

Something to note is that I previously had another stick of Corsair RAM installed for about two years until a few days ago where after an update I would just get a backlit black screen. After removing the old stick it booted fine. I'm almost certain it was detecting the RAM just fine before, but now without proof I'm kind of doubting myself.

Comment: Can you explain why you are distinguishing between "built in" and the "extra slot"? Is the "built in" memory soldered to the board and there is actually only one slot for RAM? Are you sure the RAM is compatible with the motherboard?  Is the exact SKU on the motherboard's published QVL? If you actually have two slots for RAM are the modules identical? RAM is best installed in identical pairs and if they are different they may not be compatible with each other especially if they do not share common timings

Comment: Yes sorry, the built in RAM is soldered to the motherboard and there is only one slot for additional memory. The RAM I've added is the same generation and speed as the soldered one

Comment: If its a different generation, like DDR3 vs DDR4 it just wouldn't fit at all. Just because they are the same max clock frequency does not mean that they share the same timings. Timings are different than clock frequency.  I suggest that you determine the model of the motherboard and find the "Qualified Vendor List" or QVL to make sure that the exact model RAM that you chose is officially compatible. Also consider that the new RAM is DOA.  Another possibility since the old RAM does not work is damage to the socket or a burned out trace or something similar leaving the socket unusable